# How to remove or deactivate a listener

Tags: java, javafx, java-8, listener

So, the way I have things set up, is that at specific conditions, I want a listener to be active, and after it has fired, stop listening for changes. Maybe I'm missing something, but I can't seem to figure out how to use the `removeListener()` function, or if that's even the way to go about doing this.

Some code:

```
        break1.setOnAction(e ->{
        final String fieldValue = manage_money.getText();
        int pp = Integer.parseInt(platinum_num.getText());
        int gp = Integer.parseInt(gold_num.getText());
        int sp = Integer.parseInt(silver_num.getText());
        int cp = Integer.parseInt(copper_num.getText());
        if (fieldValue != null && fieldValue.matches("\\d+")) {
            int value = Integer.parseInt(manage_money.getText());
            if (silver.isSelected()){
                if (value <= sp){
                    try {
                        tooltip_inv.getChildren().addAll(select);
                        radio_money2.selectedToggleProperty().addListener(((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                            if (newValue == copper){
                                silver_num.setText(Integer.toString(sp - value));
                                copper_num.setText(Integer.toString(cp + value * 10));
                                manage_money.clear();
                                tooltip_inv.getChildren().clear();
                            }
                        }));
                    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
                    }
                }else{
                    manage_money.setText("ERR");
                }
            }
        }else{
            manage_money.setText("NaN");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you've done in your example is you've defined a listener in your addListener method. You don't have any reference to it except there! One way to fix this is to simply create a variable for it and keep it somewhere, something like

```
ChangeListener listener = new ChangeListener(){
    @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue observable, Object oldValue, Object newValue) {
            // your code here
        }
};
radio_money2.selectedToggleProperty().addListener(listener);
radio_money2.selectedToggleProperty().removeListener(listener);
```

Comment: Hey, thanks! I had thought that it was something like that I had to do, but for some reason I couldn't figure out how to create a listener that way.

Comment: You can still use lambda statements.

Comment: @MouseEvent yes, you could still use lambda statements, but I thought that this was clearer, since it seemed like the confusion came from using lambda statements without a clear understanding of what it was they were doing.